# Packing nonreactive libraries to reactive wrappers

Tags: javascript, meteor, fullcalendar, meteor-blaze

What's the general way of doing this? I have problems with fullcalendar reactive wrapper. Official version (rzymek) unfortunately doesn't work properly, so I decided to create my own wrapper. I used rendered and destroyed events for plugin instance initialization and destruction, but ... it's not working reactively (to be clear, it works exactly like rzymek version). What's wrong?

EDIT: My problem aren't only reactive events, I want full calendar fully reactive, that means, every change of inicialization arguments should rerender calendar to new state.

Answer (score 1):

Fullcalendar is a bit tricky to get working reactively. An OK hack that I ended up using was wrapping a Collection.find() call and the refetchEvent in an autorun like so:

```
Template.foo.onRendered(function() {
  this.autorun(function() {
    YourCollection.find({});
    $(".calendar").fullCalendar("refetchEvents");
  });
});
```

So any updates you make to `YourCollection` will trigger a refetchEvent which will execute your `events` and `eventRender` fullcalender callback, where you can then update the calender.

Comment: Thanks, but I need this behavior with all inicialization arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was, that Blaze doesn't rerender template when it's arguments changes. That's really strange. How to solve this? Use Template.currentData() which is reactive source returning actual template data context. Next step is: in onRendered callback, we start autorun which listen to changes in template data context and rerender calendar according to changes.

And finally, we have reactive fullcalendar.